# Existence of a lift

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, derived-categories

Let $V_1$, $V_2$, $V_3$,  $V_4$ be four holomorphic vector bundles over  a smooth manifold. Let $f_1\in Hom(V_0,V_1)$, $f_2\in Ext^1(V_1,V_2)$ and $f_3\in Hom(V_2,V_3)$, such that $f_2\circ f_1=0$ and $f_3\circ f_2=0$. Consider an extention $V_2\xrightarrow{i} V\xrightarrow{g} V_1\rightarrow 0$, with the class of $f_2$. Then there exists morphisms $h_1:V_0\rightarrow V$ and $h_2:V\rightarrow V_3$ such that $f_1=g\circ h_1$ and $f_3=h_2\circ i$. My question is: why do they exist? Is there any general criteria?

Comment: $f_2\circ f_1=0$ means that the short exact sequence obtained by pullback of $g$ and $f_1$ splits (on the right), so you obtain a map $V_0\to {\rm pb}(g,f_1)\to V$.

Comment: I understood that if the sequence obtained by the pullback splits, then I get the map I wish. However I don't get why the fact that $f_2\circ f_1=0$ implies the splitting.

Comment: The zero element in the extension group is the split extension. Any representative of it is a split exact sequence.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!